# How do I customize this navigation button icon?

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to change things like the border. I already know how to change the 3 bar colours like this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**Edit**

SOLUTION

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle { 
border: none; 
}
```

Comment: Not to sound rude, but did you do any research, for instance Googling how to change borders in CSS? There's literally a [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) property. It is expected that you have attempted to do some research of your problem and attempted to overcome it before posting on SO. Researching and attempting beforehand will ultimately improve your skills as a coder, rather than just posting for help immediately and using the given answers without necessarily understanding them.

Comment: Change things like border? Yes, please go ahead and change `border-color`, `border-width` etc (whichever you need). Are you having any problems doing it? If yes, let us know what is the problem or post your code/demo.

Comment: use border:1px solid white; border-radius: 3px; property,

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what to target. If I add border property to ".navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar" it doesn't work.

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent - Then use `!important` along with the value. ----> `border-radius: 3px !important`.

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent You're going to need to post your markup in addition to your CSS. CSS isn't really meaningful without the markup it targets.

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent: That is better. You have now said us what you tried and didn't work. Now show us your markup (HTML) and existing CSS.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: Please don't recommend use of `!important` mate. There are better ways (possibly) to achieve what is needed.

Comment: @Harry - True, but we are playing blind here.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Better to ask for more information than give poor practice as advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to style it.

```css
.icon-bar {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
body {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar">☰</div>
```

Comment: I used this to remove the border: .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

add this to your class to modify the border radius for example and there is too many other manipulation you can do with the border you can check all of them here [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) :

```
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
```